# how to use session in ajax file using codeigniter

Tags: session, codeigniter

there is a php file that i am calling using ajax through a view. 
xmlhttp.open("GET","/my/path/to/background_file.php");

that php file is doing some background process and hence i do not need any controller/ view for that file. its an independent file.

considering that i do not need any controller/ view for that php file, can i access session variables there ? how ?

where should i keep these kind of php files which do not need any view/ controller?

thanks in advance. i am using codeIgniter 1.7.2

dev

Answer (score 0):

If you want to access objects in Codeigniters session array, I'd suggest making your ajax file a controller. It's pretty common to create an ajax controller so you can access Codeigniter's functionality. Of course, you don't need a view connected to the controller, you simply echo json_encode($data) to return any required data.

Comment: I will try that ... and how do i give the path to that controller from javascript ? ...as of now i am using this mlhttp.open("GET","/my/path/to/background_file.php"); ... in calling a controller file through javascript is there a proper way ?

Comment: ok. so it can be called using '<?php echo base_url(); ?>'+'/controller/function'

Comment: Yeah that's exactly right, providing that the javascript is in a CI view. If the javascript is in a seperate .js file, <?php ?> won't work. I solve this problem by putting one line of javascript in my header view: var base_url = '<?php echo bse_url(); ?>';, then if you have external .js files, you can use base_url + 'controller/function' to access the controller.